# Configure a stubbed factory that returns a promise from a deferred in a unit test?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, dependency-injection, stubbing

I am writing an AngularJs unit test where I need to stub out a factory that returns a promise when invoked. I will later resolve the promise manually in my tests by using a locally scoped deferred object.

I am trying to do

```
  let currentUser
  beforeEach(module(($q, $provide) => {
    currentUser = $q.defer()
    $provide.factory('gettingCurrentUser', () => currentUser.promise)
  }))
```

But this will not work since it seems like `$q` cannot be injected into a `module` block. Of course if I change it to an `inject` block, `$provide` is no longer injectable!

I can hack around this issue a dozen different ways, but it seems too straightforward to be an edge case that requires hacking.

What is the "correct AngularJs" way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple recipe to do this is to return local variable that will be assigned to an appropriate promise in another block (but before instantiating this service).

```
  let currentUserPromise;

  beforeEach(module(($provide) => {
    $provide.factory('gettingCurrentUser', () => currentUserPromise)
  }));

  beforeEach(inject(($q) => {
    currentUserPromise = $q.resolve(...);
  }));

  it(inject((serviceThatDependsOnGettingCurrentUser) => {
    ...
  }));
```

Comment: Yeah, this is one of the approaches I was talking about when I said by "I can hack around this", is it really the recommended way of dealing with the issue? It seems so hacky

Comment: It's usual. I find the approaches that use deferreds more clumsy. The reason why it may seem 'hacky' is that this kind of factory services that return not class instances but something else result in such problems. When you follow OOP paradigms and have some class method like `auth.getCurrentUser`, you won't have this problem. You can stub it with Jasmine createSpyObj or createSpy and assign `returnValue` any moment.